# Android DatePickerDialog date highlighted in all years?

Tags: android, datepicker

I have created a `DatePickerDialog` and passed a custom year, date, day (ex, I have passed Jan, 26th, 2017).It shows me Jan 26th is highlighted in all years. How can I avoid that and show Jan 26th selected only in 2017?

```
 DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            //TODO use selected date
        }
    }, year, month, day);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().updateDate(2017, 0, 26);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().getMaxDate());
    datePickerDialog.setTitle("Pick date");
    datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: This is a bug in DatePicker itself. Not sure in which version it was fixed, but API 26 has it, API 29 doesn't. [Commit that fixed it](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/2e654f764c94358381ebce7b4624cb734a099c6e).

Probably no way around it unless you use some custom date picker, like [MaterialDatePicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/datepicker/MaterialDatePicker)

Answer (score -1):

```
@shabhan, used this code.

 final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int mYear,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                        year = mYear;
                        month = monthOfYear;
                        day = dayOfMonth;

                        tvBirthDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                                .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year).append(" "));

                    }
                }, month, day, year);

        dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```